# Spring not finding a property file in my jar

Tags: java, spring, jar, classloader

I have a program that works perfectly in eclipse, but when exported as a jar, spring initialization is failing because it claims it can't find

```
file:/C:/BLM/UMC_CLI/umc_cli.jar!/mydir/umc.properties
```

I tried both with and without the leading slash in the app-config.xml.  Didn't make a difference.  Like I said, it works in eclipse before jarring, AND when I put test code in, I can find that umc.properties via the system classloader.  And I can see that it IS there in the jar...in the same directory as the app-config.xml.

Exact message:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'localPropertyFile' defined in class path resource [mydir/app-config.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sysProperties' while setting bean property 'properties'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sysProperties' defined in class path resource [mydir/app-config.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'DatabaseConfiguration' while setting bean property 'targetObject'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'DatabaseConfiguration' defined in class path resource [mydir/app-config.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.io.File' for property 'propertyFile'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not retrieve file for class path resource [mydir/umc.properties]: class path resource [mydir/umc.properties] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:/C:/BLM/UMC_CLI/umc_cli.jar!/mydir/umc.properties
```

Java command line:

```
java -Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.object.disableEndpointIdentification=true -Djava.ext.dirs=.;.\umc_cli_lib\ -jar umc_cli.jar
```

Comment: I just discovered that if I export the entire mydir outside the jar and include it in the classpath separately, it finds it.  So something about being in the jar breaks it...even if it already found a file in that EXACT SAME DIRECTORY (the app-config.xml).  I'd rather no have to extract this everytime I cut a jar.  Is there a config thing to resolve this?

Comment: please try --spring.config.location to point out where config file when starting jar.